# Windows XP Hangs on Welcome Screen Until Ctrl + Alt + Del is Pressed

Tags: windows-xp, freeze, boot

I'm in a Gr. 12 computer engineering class, and we're setting up these old Pentium 4 machines, installing some software, and Ghosting them to get to know the Ghosting process.

So I was lucky and picked a machine that had no problems. Then I did a fresh install of Windows XP Professional SP2. In the beginning, I installed Firefox, and LibreOffice. After the weekend, I went back to the machine, and it hung for about 5 mins at the Welcome Screen. I rebooted, and the same thing happened.

A kid came over, and jokingly pressed Ctrl + Alt + Del, and what do you know? The HDD starts making sounds, the HDD light starts flickering, and the desktop and taskbar showed up. I thought it was a coincidence, but it still hung at the Welcome Screen every time I boot. The HDD light rarely flashes, nor does the HDD make any sounds, until I press Ctrl + Alt + Del. Why is this happening? Can't be a coincidence every time.

Specs:

- HP d530 CMT
- Pentium 4 (I'll find and add the # tomorrow) > 1.5 GHz
- 1 GB DDR (4x 256MB)
- Intel Graphics "Extreme" 2
- <s>2x WD400 Caviar IDE (40GB each, not in RAID)</s>
- 1x WD400 Caviar IDE 40GB
- Windows XP Professional <s>SP2</s> SP3 32 bits

Extra information:

- Motherboard battery is drained, BIOS settings aren't saved sometimes, and time stops after shutdown.
- No passwords
- 1 User account
- No "Press Ctrl + Alt + Del to login" dialog
- The board banned us from connecting these machines to the Internet. I get no updates, and I have to download everything from the school's computers, and transfer via flash drive. There is wireless but we don't have receivers.

Update:

- Installed SP3
- Finished drive cloning/ghosting, and removed the clone drive for storage inside my teacher's cabinet

Comment: try installing SP3? are you sysprepping these systems before ghosting?

Comment: Similar: [During Windows XP startup, why do I sometimes have to press Enter or Esc at the welcome screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/6852/during-windows-xp-startup-why-do-i-sometimes-have-to-press-enter-or-esc-at-the?rq=1).  Is it ONLY C+A+D that wakes it up, or do other key presses also work? Have you tried starting it in safe mode? Does it behave the same way? How about with a NOT dead BIOS battery? How about with no KB/mouse attached?

Comment: Also, have you seen and tried things suggested in [How to diagnose a freeze on startup in Windows XP?](http://superuser.com/questions/83101/how-to-diagnose-a-freeze-on-startup-in-windows-xp)

Comment: I'll see if I can find the time to test all this tomorrow. I'm in the process of installing SP3, and I have to do the ghosting tomorrow, but we pretty much get to use these machines whenever we want. Hopefully I can find and fix the problem before it vanishes

Comment: ATM I'm always in a hurry to install something so I can get to the ghosting, so I've only tried C+A+D

Comment: Only C+A+D works. Esc, Enter, the other keys have no effect at all

Comment: Installed SP3, problem still persists

Comment: I know my dad's laptop he got from his work used to have this screen, saying 'Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to continue'. It might be the same thing, but it somehow doesn't show you the message box. I'm not sure where to disable it though..